# Unexpected behaviour of np.sum which acts as np.ravel

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I have a list of list of numbers and I want to sum all the numbers (regardless the list of lists). This should be a piece of cake for np.sum
In fact if we have

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
np.sum(a)
```

returns 10

By the way if we have

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]
np.sum(a)
```

returns

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

It seems quite weird to me...

Comment: The second one is not a valid numpy array. Which is why np.sum can't handle it. Honestly, i would have though that that would throw an error of some kind.

Comment: And unless you already have a numpy array, the builtin sum is actually faster most of the time.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Note: this does not happen with numpy 1.5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I would hazard to guess that the answer here is pretty simple.

`np.sum` will evaluate the two lists and realise that it can't store their values in a normal array. It will therefore make an object array:

```
In [99]: x = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]

In [100]: np.array(x)
Out[100]: array([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=object)
```

When it comes to sum the elements of the array it will use the objects `__add__` operator.

The addition of the two objects is:

```
In [103]: [1,2] + [3,4,5]
Out[103]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Therefore:

```
In [104]: np.sum([[1,2],[3,4,5]])
Out[104]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I do not have any idea to verify your hypotesis but it looks like quite convincing

Comment: The easy way to verify it would be to make two random objects which have an `__add__` operator. Try and sum a list of two or more of them and see what is produced.